# Использование классов для отрисовки интерфеса tkinter. Как убить фрейм

Tags: python-3.x, классы, tkinter

изучаю Python и классы, подскажите как правильно сделать, есть интефейс написанный на tkinter, все в отдельных файлах:

Задача отрисовывать отдельные фреймы при вызове функций кнопкой, к каждой кнопке прикручена функция вызывающая класс соответсвующего фрейма, при запуске кода по умолчанию отрисовываются кнопки и дефолтный фрейм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В свою очередь кнопки Frame_Button переключают Frame_Default на Frame_A и Frame_B соответсвенно.

Однако при вызове функции frame_a или frame_b, Frame_Default не удаляется, а переносится в 3-й столбец.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста, почему это происходит, и как убить этот фрейм при вызове функций frame_a или frame_b.

Код main:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from frame_buttons import Frame_Button
from frame_defalt import Frame_Default

class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self.parent = parent
       self.parent.title("main")
       self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.parent['padx'] = 10
       self.parent['pady'] = 10

       Frame_Button_Class = Frame_Button(self)
       Frame_Button_Class.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

       Frame_Default_Class = Frame_Default(self)
       Frame_Default_Class.grid(row=1, column=2)

       self.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("main")
    ex = MainWindow(root)
    root.geometry("560x120")
    root.mainloop()
```

Код frame_buttons:

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import ttk
 from frame_a import Frame_A
 from frame_b import Frame_B

 class Frame_Button(ttk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()

     def create_widgets(self):    

        button_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, width=115, height=100,  text="Buttons", relief=tk.RIDGE)
        button_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        button_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        button_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        button_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        button_a = ttk.Button(button_frame, width=15, text="Frame A", command=lambda: frame_a())
        button_a.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.N, pady=1)

        button_b = ttk.Button(button_frame, width=15, text="Frame B", command=lambda: frame_b())
        button_b.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.N, pady=1)


        def frame_a():

            Frame_A_Class = Frame_A(self)
            Frame_A_Class.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5)

        def frame_b():

            Frame_B_Class = Frame_B(self)
            Frame_B_Class.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5)
```

Код frame_default:

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import ttk


 class Frame_Default(ttk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()

     def create_widgets(self):

         welcome_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, width=200, height=100,
                                        text="Default", relief=tk.RIDGE)
         welcome_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
         welcome_frame.grid_propagate(False)

         welcome_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
         welcome_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

         label = tk.Label(welcome_frame, text="Welcome")
         label.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Код frame_a и frame_b по своей сути одинаковые:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Frame_A(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

       frame_a = ttk.LabelFrame(self, width=200, height=100,   text="Frame A", relief=tk.RIDGE)
       frame_a.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
       frame_a.grid_propagate(False)

       frame_a.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       frame_a.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    label = tk.Label(frame_a, text="FRAME A Bla Bla Bla")
    label.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: Frame_Default_Class.destroy()

Comment: Спасибо, а почему он перемещается в 3-й стоблец?

Comment: welcome_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S) c этим что то связано разбираться с кодом нет времени